# How to get error message from IDP(ADFS) when SAML response has status as Responder?

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs2.0

If SAML Response has the status as "status:Responder",

**According SAML spec:**

> urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder The request could not be performed due to an error on the part of the SAML responder or SAML authority.

**We expect the IDP should send the error message along with the response.**

In ADFS event viewer, we can find out why SAML request failed, however we don't have access to ADFS sever in production environment.

Is it possible to get the error message inside SAML response in case if the authentication fails?

Comment: No - you have to ask for the ADFS event log entries.

Comment: Can we get error codes from SAML response ?

Comment: Do we always get Status as Responder in case of any error on IDP(ADFS) ?

There are other status codes as well like VersionMismatch,AuthnFailed,InvalidAttrNameOrValue,RequestDenied etc. 

In above case also will we get error code as Responder ?

Comment: I can't remember ever seeing other codes.